Scripting For Production Setup
I am currently setting up a pipeline to simplify my 3D production. During linking layers for compositing I find it difficult each time to link the separate passes to the desired output. Is there an easy way to do this?
I currently use a blend file with already set up group nodes in it for the different layers. One for all beauty passes, one for all utility passes, crypto, etc. But how do I go about linking them faster?
And secondly, is it possible to set it up in a way so that what viewlayer we have set up in the current is what name would appear on the rendered image sequence? For example, in Substance Painter, there are tokens that correctly follow the object name and the type of map it exports when rendering. I'm looking for a method like that.
Any help would be appreciated!

Maybe your are looking for this addon.
